# How do I create a variable with a number based on an element's number position using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, variables, numbers

Here's an example code:

```
<ul>
     <li>One</li>
     <li>Two</li>
     <li>Three</li>
     <li>Four</li>
</ul>
```

Using Jquery, if a user clicks the "third" li, create a variable with "3"

Comment: what about an Array Variable?

Comment: @DevlshOne, sorry I did not provide a code attempt.  My code attempt was incomplete, so I decided it would be best if I created an example.  I started writing the code and then thought about using :eq... but I wasn't sure if :eq was the right approach, so I got stumped.

Answer (score 2):

Get the index of the `li` element:

```
var variable;
$("ul li").on("click", function () {
    variable = $(this).index() + 1;
    alert(variable);
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/CXvpT/)

---

From [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/index/):

### `.index()`

> .index() Returns: Number
>
> Description: Search for a given element from among the matched elements.

Comment: @LordPeasantTard Then don't forget to accept it clicking `✔` icon from the left of answer. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

```
var liNumber = 0;

$('li').click(function(){
    liNumber = $(this).index() + 1;
})
```